# Extend rails model in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails engine to augment a host app specifically to aid in development. For example, the engine will have a UI that will allow you to toggle features on or off in the host app so that dev's can see how the app performs in either case.

Originally I intended to extend the models from the parent application inside of the engine but I have not been able to find a straightforward way to do this.

I understand that generally speaking, this approach tightly couples the two applications so it's not necessarily ideal, but in my instance coupling is acceptable as the engine is only for developing this particular application.

I have looked at creating decorators inside of the engine and including them into the parent - I don't love the idea in particular because the decorators are meant *only* for dev purposes and I don't want anything included going to production.

I am open to suggestions as to the best approach. Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT - Adding Clarity...

We have a legacy app that can be difficult to reason about. Often times a combination of values across tables/fields work together to determine if a feature is enabled and how it will behave. The idea was to create an engine that functions specifically to help new and existing team members understand that a given feature is on (or turn it on) without having to know what combination of fields to look at or toggle in the db.

As an extension of this idea, let's say that I want to show in the UI that feature `X` is enabled. Feature `X` is enabled if `model.foo` is `true` and `model.bar` is `false`. Rather than have to have template logic that says `if model.foo is true and model.bar is false then feature X is on`, I'd like to be able to define a method that says `if model.feature_x_enabled? then feature X is enabled`.

I could just put this logic in the application model but it will only be used by the engine for now and adding this type of thing in wont make the app itself any easier to understand. So I wanted to find a good encapsulation for this inside of the engine.

I hope that make more sense.

Comment: Confused what you're asking. Are you making a Rails application to be used as a server for phone app or another Rails application? And you're end game is for that server to have the same db, models as the already existing application?

Comment: @Rocco - I added some extra details above - and although it may seem prudent to just refactor, I would generally agree but my example is contrived and the risk in doing so is too high for us right now. Thanks.